# Evaluating an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics

Gaussian-profile initial condition has the solution,

$$\phi (r,t)=\frac{R^{3}}{2}\frac{A}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty
}ke^{-R^{2}k^{2}/4}\frac{\sin (kr)}{r}\cos (\omega t)\ dk,$$

where A is an arbitrary initial amplitude and the dispersion relation is $\omega= (k^2 + \omega^2_{mass})^\frac{1}{2}$, where the mass frequency $ \omega_{mass}= \sqrt{2}$.
Details : see the [article equation 4](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922).
Now how do we get the equation:

$$\phi (0,t)=\frac{A_{0}}{\left( 1+\frac{2t^{2}}{R^{4}}\right) ^{\frac{3}{4}}}\cos \left( \sqrt{2}t+\frac{3}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left[ \frac{\sqrt{2}t}{R^{2}}\right] \right) .$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is some other equation used to derive $\phi (0,t)$.  The integrand in the general $\phi (r, t)$ is indeterminate when $r=0$.

Comment: Maybe $\lim_{r\to0}\phi(r,t)$?

Comment: Celtschk I think so. They followed the the equation (22-25) http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9503217.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They take the limit $r\to0$ to obtain
$$
\phi (0,t)=\frac{R^{3}}{2}\frac{A}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{0}^{\infty
}k^2e^{-R^{2}k^{2}/4}\cos (\sqrt{k^2+2} t)\ dk.
$$
Then, since the exponent $e^{-R^{2}k^{2}/4}$ goes very quickly to zero as $k$ goes to infinity, the authors say that  the integral is dominated by small values of $k$, $k\sim 2R^{-1}$. For whose values the root  in $\cos (\sqrt{k^2+2} t)$ is approximated as $\sqrt{k^2+2}=\sqrt2\sqrt{k^2/2+1}\approx \sqrt2(1+k^2/4)\ $.  Now if to add an imaginary part,
$$
\cos(\sqrt2(t+tk^2/4))+i\sin (\sqrt2(t+tk^2/4))= e^{i\sqrt2(t+tk^2/4)},
$$
the integral turns into
$$
\frac{R^3 e^{i \sqrt{2} t} A}{2\sqrt{\pi }} \int_0^{\infty } k^2
   e^{-\frac{1}{4} k^2 R^2} e^{\frac{1}{4} i \sqrt{2} k^2
   t} \, dk=
\frac{R^3 e^{i \sqrt{2} t} A}{2\sqrt{\pi }} \int_0^{\infty } k^2
   e^{-\frac{1}{4}(  R^2-i \sqrt{2}  t)k^2} \, dk=
$$
$$
\frac{AR^3 e^{i \sqrt{2} t}}{\left(R^2-i \sqrt{2}
   t\right){}^{3/2}}.
$$
Taking the real part gives the answer:
$$
\phi (0,t)\approx\frac{A}{\left( 1+\frac{2t^{2}}{R^{4}}\right) ^{\frac{3}{4}}}\cos \left( \sqrt{2}t+\frac{3}{2}\tan ^{-1}\left[ \frac{\sqrt{2}t}{R^{2}}\right] \right).
$$

Comment: Can you please explain a bit that why did we add imaginary term? And how  did  $ k∼2R^{−1}$ arise?

Comment: @ComplexGuy the imaginary part is added since it allows to compute the integral easily:
$$
\int_0^\infty k^2e^{-Ck^2}\,dk=\large|y=Ck^2\large|=
2C^{-3}\int_0^\infty y^{1/2}e^{-y}\,dy=2C^{-3}\Gamma(1/2)=2\sqrt\pi C^{-3}.
$$


The authors consider the segment  $0\le k\le 2R^{-1}$ because it gives the main contribution to the integral. The exponent $e^{-R^2k^2/4}\ge e^{-1}$ here. If to take, say, $k= 4R^{-1}$ then $e^{-R^2k^2/4}=e^{-4}=0.018\ldots$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434290/evaluating-decay-rate/434736?noredirect=1#comment930634_434736
check the question please, if you have time.