# Evaluating decay rate with trigonometric explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, problem-solving

According to the [equation 4](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922), 
$$\phi(0,t)= \frac{A_0}{(1+\frac{2t^2}{R^4})^{3/4}}\cos \left(\sqrt2 t+ \frac{3}{2}\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt2 t}{R^2}\right]\right)\tag{1}$$
what conditions makes, $$\cos \left(\sqrt2 t+ \frac{3}{2}\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt2 t}{R^2}\right]\right)=1$$
so the equation (1) will be

$$\phi(0,t)= \frac{A_0}{(1+\frac{2t^2}{R^4})^{3/4}}$$
The author used the [article reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9503217) to establish the equation 
$$\frac{1}{2} \Gamma_{lin}= \frac{1}{\tau_{linear}} \approx \frac{1.196}{\omega_{mass}} \approx \frac{.846}{R^2}$$
but I didn't get any argument there, can you explain this a bit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you read carefully, the authors clearly state that

> $$
> \phi(0,t) = \frac{A_0}{\left(1 + \frac{2 t^2}{R^4}\right)^{3/4}}\cos\left(\sqrt{2}t + \frac{3}{2} \tan^{-1} \left[\frac{\sqrt{2}t}{R^2}\right]\right), \tag{4}
> $$
>   whos envelope of oscillation is given by $\phi(0,t) = A_0/(1 + 2t^2/R^4)^{3/4}$, which reaches $1/e$ of its initial value in a time given by $\mathcal{T}_{linear} \simeq .836\omega_{mass} R^2$. This yields the linear decay width
>   $$
> \frac{1}{2}\Gamma_{lin} = \frac{1}{\mathcal{T}_{linear}} \simeq \frac{1.196}{\omega_{mass}R^2} \simeq \frac{.846}{R^2}. \tag{5}
> $$

The key here is the statement "*which reaches $1/e$ of its initial value at time given by...*"

The time where the oscillon reaches a fraction $1/e$ of its initial value is
$$
\frac{A_0}{e} = \frac{A_0}{\left(1 + \frac{2 t^2}{R^4}\right)^{3/4}}
$$

Solving for $t$,
$$
t = \left(\frac{e^{4/3} - 1}{2}\right)^{1/2} R^2.
$$
Now, using that $\omega_{mass} = \sqrt{2}$, we have
$$
\mathcal{T}_{linear} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\frac{e^{4/3} - 1}{2}\right)^{1/2} \omega_{mass} R^2 \simeq 0.836 \omega_{mass}R^2,
$$
and eq. (5) follows.

**EDIT**
Lets take a look of the graph of $\phi(0,t)$:

$\hskip1in$![image]

It's clear that the oscillation decays, with a decay rate of $A_0/(1 + 2t^2/R^2)^{3/4}$. If we plot this decay rate,

$\hskip1in$![image]

The dashed curves are the envelopes of the field $\phi(0,t)$. What the authors are definining as $\mathcal{T}_{linear}$, is the point in time where the envelope has reduced it's amplitude by $1/e$. In this case, $2/e \simeq 0.736$:

$\hskip1in$[image]

Comment: So, we are considering intial value that means $t\rightarrow 0$ ? and $$\cos \left(\sqrt2 t+ \frac{3}{2}\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt2 t}{R^2}\right]\right) \rightarrow 1$$?

Comment: No. The authors are talking about the **envelope** of the field. You know that $|\phi| \le A_0/(1 + 2 t^2/R^4)^{3/4}$, so the field will oscillate between these values.

Comment: Can you please explian a bit about the envelope hence author chose the condition?

Comment: @ComplexGuy See the edit.

Comment: Owaw Thanks, got it now, but Can I get the input code that you drew the graph or  Mathematica input?

Comment: @ComplexGuy `Show[Plot[Evaluate[{A/(1 + 2  t^2/R^4)^(3/4) Cos[Sqrt[2] t + 3/2 ArcTan[(Sqrt[2] t)/R^2]], A/(1 + 2  t^2/R^4)^(3/4), -(A/(1 + 2  t^2/R^4)^(3/4)), A/E} /. {A -> 2, R -> 3}], {t, 0, 12}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}, Blue}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "\[Phi](0,t)"}, ImageSize -> 400], Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[{((E^(4/3) - 1)/2)^(1/2) R^2, A/E}], {Black, Line[{{((E^(4/3) - 1)/2)^(1/2) R^2, 0}, {((E^(4/3) - 1)/2)^(1/2) R^2, A/E}}]}}] /. {A -> 2, R -> 3}]`

Comment: Owaw, you are adept at Mathematica, 
i have several tries for a equation but everytime got disimilar in the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434768/numerical-simulation-problem-in-graph-plotting,
Can you check please, if you have time. 
I'm glad to get you here. :-)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438114/what-is-decay-width

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually find such $t$ to make the inside equal to points where $cos(\theta)=1.$ You only need that as $t\to \infty$ there will be a sequence of $t$ values for which $\theta =2n\pi$. From your expression,
$$\theta=\sqrt2 t+ \frac{3}{2}\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt2 t}{R^2}\right],$$
and the arctan part added is bounded, while $\sqrt2t\to \infty$ This means $\theta \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$, and $\theta$ is a continuous function of $t$, which forces $\theta$ to take on infinitely many values of the form $\theta =2n\pi$, so that your cosine term will be $1$ for all those values. It will similarly be $-1$ infinitely often, making the whole $\cos \theta$ oscillate in $[-1,1]$ (hitting both extremes infinitely often as $t \to \infty$) So the damping factor in front is definitely the best for the absolute value of your function $\phi(0,t).$

ADDED: The OP requests in comments more explanation about $\cos \theta=1$ happening infinitely often as $t \to \infty$. For each $t$ there is a value of $\theta(t)$ given by the above formula (which was the inside of the function cosine in the OP). This function $\theta(t)$ is a continuous function of $t$, and the above argument shows it goes to $\infty$ as $t \to \infty.$ Now imagine the number line with a "tick mark" at every point where the cosine is $1$ (these are the points $2\pi n$ since cosine is periodic and is $1$ only at $0$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. Now $\theta(t)$ starts out on this line at some point $\theta(0)$, and as $t$ increases, $\theta(t)$ may move forward or backward at any one time (because of the arctangent in the formula), but eventually $\theta(t)$ moves all the way from $\theta(0)$ to $+\infty$. So in the process, $\theta(t)$ will cross through all the tick marks to the right of $\theta(0)$, so that at each such $t$ value where $\theta(t)$ crosses a tick mark we will have $\cos(\theta(t))=1.$

Comment: As t tends to infinity so as $\theta$ then why $\cos \infty$ will give us value 1 ?

Comment: It isn't $\cos \infty$ which is $1$, since $\cos \infty$ has no meaning. ($\infty$ is not a real number.) What it means is that for example if at some point $\theta(t)=1000$ then for some slightly larger $t$, $\theta(t)$ must become $320\pi+\pi/2= 1006.88...,$ and at that $t$ value you'll have $\cos\theta=1.$

Comment: Sorry my bad $320\pi+\pi/2= 1006.88...,$ I didn't get you here. Why are you guessing $\frac{\pi}{2}$ at last , why not $\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{\pi}{6}$?

Comment: @ComplexGuy I've added to my answer (see section at end labeled "ADDED") explaining the idea of why $\cos\theta$ must become $1$ infinitely often as $t \to \infty.$

Comment: but by this same argument cant we prove $cos \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$? 
is there any mathematical argument that will explain more explicitly?

Comment: So it was an approximation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9501/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-complex-guy)