# combination into an aggregate equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Radiation flux ids defined by, 
$$\phi = - \frac{\dot E}{S} = \frac {1}{2} (\omega_{rad})^2\frac{ \omega_{rad}}{k_{rad}} = \frac {1}{2} \delta^2 \Omega(\omega_{rad})^2\frac{ \omega_{rad}^3}{k_{rad}} \tag{1}$$
Where S is the surface area, A is the amplitude, $k_{rad}$ is the wave number. 
where A is defined as, 
$$A= \int_{\omega_{mass}}^{\infty} \Omega(\omega) d\omega$$
and $$\Omega(\omega)= F(\omega)\bar b(\omega)  \tag{2}$$
and $$F(\omega)= - \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{\dot A}{1 + \chi} (\omega-\omega_{nl})^{-2}  \tag{3}$$
[By combing these above equations (article page no 4, equations 19)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922) how do we get?
$$\eta \frac{dE}{dt}+ \left(\frac{dA}{dt}\right)^2=0$$

Comment: This is a completely ill posed question. You are not giving all the information needed to derive the last equation which, by the way, is not correct. What have you done? Where are you stuck? Have you tried something? It looks like a trivial substitution to me.

Comment: @Pragabhava , I tried several way to combine them but failed. May be this is a longer process.Actually I didn't get them how they did, if anyone put here some hints then I can try some  attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have that
$$
\frac{1}{S}\frac{d E}{dt} + \frac{1}{2} \delta^2 \Omega(\omega_{rad})^2 \frac{\omega_{rad}^3}{k_{rad}} = 0
$$
Now, given that
$$
\Omega(\omega) = \mathcal{F}(\omega) \tilde{b}(\omega)
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{F}(\omega) = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\dot{A}}{1 + \chi}(\omega - \omega_{nl})^{-2}
$$
you have that
$$
\Omega(\omega_{rad}) =  -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\dot{A}}{1 + \chi}(\omega_{rad} - \omega_{nl})^{-2}\tilde{b}(\omega_{rad})
$$
which in turn means that
$$
\frac{1}{S}\frac{d E}{dt} + \frac{1}{\pi} \delta^2 \frac{\dot{A}^2}{(1 + \chi)^2} \frac{\omega_{rad}^3 \tilde{b}^2(\omega_{rad})}{k_{rad}(\omega_{rad} - \omega_{nl})^4} = 0
$$
and then
$$
\frac{\pi (1 + \chi)^2 (\omega_{rad} - \omega_{nl})^4 k_{rad}}{c_d R^{d-1} \omega_{rad}^3 \delta^2 \tilde{b}^2(\omega_{rad})} \frac{d E}{d t} + \left(\frac{d A}{d t}\right)^2 = \eta \frac{d E}{d t} + \left(\frac{d A}{d t}\right)^2 = 0
$$
where
$$
\eta = \frac{\pi (1 + \chi)^2 (\omega_{rad} - \omega_{nl})^4 k_{rad}}{c_d R^{d-1} \omega_{rad}^3 \delta^2 \tilde{b}^2(\omega_{rad})}.
$$

Comment: If $\Phi$ is the flux and $\bar E$ is the energy per unit time then how this equation $$\eta \frac{dE}{dt}+ \left(\frac{dA}{dt}\right)^2=0$$ refers nonlinear behaviour, I mean how do I surmise that, the equation will not support superimposition principle or the equation will have nonlinear properties?

Comment: And thnx a lot, your answer is canonical and I understood explictly, 
If you have time then plz have a look, I'm still confused about these: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434768/numerical-simulation-problem-in-graph-plotting

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434290/evaluating-decay-rate-with-trigonometric-explanation

Comment: @ComplexGuy In what context does the superimposition principle is refered? If you mean putting two oscillons together, then my guess is that the approximations should be done with a two-peak like function.

Comment: Long live oscillons means that will take long time in decaying completely, 
I said how can the energy equation conclude  that Life time of a oscillons will be huge?